# Using database TEXT to IMAGE using mysqli_fetch_row

Tags: php, mysql, database, mysqli, fetch

I have this code:

```
$query = "SELECT vidRoles FROM videoinformation";

if ($result = mysqli_query($con, $query)) {

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result)) {
        $values = explode(',',$row[0]);
        foreach($values as $v)
           printf ("<img src=\"roles/%s.jpg\">", $v);
    }

    mysqli_free_result($result);
}
```

BUT instead of display:

```
<img src="roles/Name1.jpg>
<img src="roles/Name2.jpg>
<img src="roles/Name3.jpg>
```

I have:

```
<img src="roles/Name1.jpg>
<img src="roles/Name2.jpg>
<img src="roles/Name3.jpg>
<img src="roles/.jpg>
<img src="roles/.jpg>
<img src="roles/.jpg>
<img src="roles/.jpg>
```

But inside vidRoles filed I have only "Name1,Name2,Name3."

 Why this empty images are show up???

Comment: can you post the structure of `$value`?

Comment: @sgt Value = "Name1,Name2,Name3"

Comment: why after this code the rest of information from database do not want to work??? Like before I can take information from database but after everything doesn't work...

Comment: @Arif_suhail_123 I have huge PHP code...code which is in the question is in the middle some where... ALL the queries(mysqli) BEFORE the code which is in the question working fine... but after... none of them are working..

Comment: This question is solved, I will create another question in a half an hour

Comment: @Arif_suhail_123  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26714364/php-code-mysqli-queries-are-not-working-after-specific-code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this -

```
foreach($values as $v) {
    if (!empty($v)) {
       printf ("<img src=\"roles/%s.jpg\">", $v);
    }
}
```

there are some `null` values present, that's why it is printing them.

Comment: May be you know... why after this code the rest of information from database do not want to work???

Comment: OK, before this code I show up images from database... (different one) BEFORE the code in the question ... all images show up.. but after all images do not show up..

Comment: check it there..this code only avoid empty values , nothing else.

Comment: not your part, I mean the full MY code which is in the question

Answer (score 2):

Please update your query to:

```
$query = "
    SELECT  vidRoles 
    FROM    videoinformation 
    WHERE   LENGTH(vidRoles) > 0
";
```

There are some rows where `vidRoles` is either blank or `NULL`.

They are causing the problem.

So, to avoid the problem, we can either do it by PHP by if else statements, or

Simply add some SQL conditions.

I think, second one is better as it has less efforts.

Comment: This is works, but another question why all the queries after this one doesn't work?  I mean  before I can take information from database, but after this code... the rest of the queries not working at all....

Answer (score 0):

change your print statement with

```
    printf ('<img src=\"roles/%s.jpg\">', $v);
```